# Making a spreadsheet out of JSON data using DataFrame from pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

There's a few posts like this already, but after following them I still encounter some issues.

```
trade = client.get_my_trades(symbol=ticker)  # fetching all trades made on the ticker IOSTBTC
print(trade)
json_trade = json.dumps(trade, indent=4)  # converting and indenting for easier readability.
print(json_trade+"\n")
json_normalised = json_normalize(trade)  # normalising with pandas for spreadsheet use
print("Normalised JSON\n", json_normalised)

json_normalised = DataFrame(pandas.read_json("logs.xlsx"))
json_normalised_str = str(json_normalised)
logs = open("logs.xlsx", "w")  # creating file to write to
logs.write(json_normalised_str)  # writing data to file, oldest first
```

This code runs fine, with no erros. However, when I check the logs.xlsx, all the data is in a single column, with spaces in between where they should be separated by columns.

For example, here's some of the JSON data:

```
[{'id': 3084149, 'orderId': 7071890, 'price': '0.00000312', 'qty': '400.00000000', 'commission': '0.00041327', 'commissionAsset': 'BNB', 'time': 1522223234240, 'isBuyer': True, 'isMaker': True, 'isBestMatch': True}, {'id': 3084468, 'orderId': 7073272, 'price': '0.00000314', 'qty': '400.00000000', 'commission': '0.00041694', 'commissionAsset': 'BNB', 'time': 1522223910252, 'isBuyer': False, 'isMaker': True, 'isBestMatch': True}]
```

What I want is for 'id' and 'orderId' and 'price' (et cetera) to have it's own column. With the above data I would have two rows of information. But instead, this is what I recieve when I use this data: [image: spreadsheet screenshot]

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `open("logs.xlsx", "w")` to create proper `xlsx` files since it will write raw text (or bytes if using `wb`) to the file. `xlsx` are more complex than that.

Instead, simply use `pandas.DataFrame.from_dict`:

```
data = [{'id': 3084149, 'orderId': 7071890, 'price': '0.00000312', 'qty': '400.00000000', 'commission': '0.00041327', 'commissionAsset': 'BNB', 'time': 1522223234240, 'isBuyer': True, 'isMaker': True, 'isBestMatch': True}, {'id': 3084468, 'orderId': 7073272, 'price': '0.00000314', 'qty': '400.00000000', 'commission': '0.00041694', 'commissionAsset': 'BNB', 'time': 1522223910252, 'isBuyer': False, 'isMaker': True, 'isBestMatch': True}]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
print(df)

#         commission commissionAsset       id  isBestMatch  isBuyer  isMaker \
#      0  0.00041327             BNB  3084149         True     True     True   
#      1  0.00041694             BNB  3084468         True    False     True   

#       orderId       price           qty           time  
#    0  7071890  0.00000312  400.00000000  1522223234240  
#    1  7073272  0.00000314  400.00000000  1522223910252
```

Then exporting to a spreadsheet is as trivial as calling `to_excel`:

```
df.to_excel('logs.xlsx')
```

[image]

And if you don't like the indexes to be exported to the spreadsheet you can use `index=False`: `df.to_excel('logs.xlsx', index=False)`. See the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) for more info.

Comment: The first part works great, but I can't seem to write to the excel doc using `df.to_excel`. I get this error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'`.

Comment: @deckador You will either need to install `openpyxl` using pip or try to use a different engine ie `df.to_excel('logs.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')`

Comment: installing `openpyxl` worked! Thank you so much. The spreadsheet looks like yours now. Again, cheers.